# How i can create a table using AS and specify the tablespace in db2?

Tags: db2

I'm trying to create a table using "AS" and specify the tablespace.
I tried something like:

```
db2 "CREATE TABLE schema.table AS (SELECT * FROM schema.tmp) IN TABSPACE01 WITH NO DATA"
```

But i get a error, it's possible to specify the tablespace when creating a table with "AS"?

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a result set to create a table `WITH NO DATA` should follow immediately after the [fullselect](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-table#sdx-synid_frag-as-result-table).

```bash
db2 "CREATE TABLE schema.table AS (SELECT * FROM schema.tmp) WITH NO DATA IN TABSPACE01"
```